# Elasticsearch Client is defaulting to localhost

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using spring.data.elasticsearch with Elasticsearch 7.14.1 in my Spring Boot (2.5.4) application.

My application.properties is something like this

```
spring.elasticsearch.rest.uris=elasticsearch:9200
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster=elasticsearch:9200
spring.data.elasticsearch.repositories.enabled=true
```

This works fine as long as the invocation is from localhost, no issues. However, when I try to bring up my Spring Boot container, I see a failure with `NoReachableHostException`

```
    reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.NoReachableHostException: Host 'localhost:9200' not reachable. Cluster state is offline.
blah-blah-service 
 Caused by: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.NoReachableHostException: Host **'localhost:9200'** not reachable. Cluster state is offline.
blah-blah-service         
 at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.reactive.SingleNodeHostProvider.lambda$lookupActiveHost$3(SingleNodeHostProvider.java:101)
```

Clearly, my suggestion to use "elasticsearch" host (defined network, that is tested and accessible from within and outside docker containers), hasn't gone well with Spring Data for whatever reason. I have even used

```
@PropertySource("classpath:mysearch.properties")
```

in my application to try and coax these properties into the app, but doesn't look like anything works. Is there something I am missing in my Elasticsearch configuration or otherwise?

PS:  I have exercised `curl http://elasticsearch:9200` from within the container and find no issues

Answer (score 2):

These configurations are Spring Boot specific, Spring Data Elasticsearch does not use them. But as far as I can see, you are configuring the transport client (cluster entry, should not be used anyway) and the **imperative** REST client, but according to the error message you are using the **reactive** REST client.

According to the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.data.spring.data.elasticsearch.client.reactive.connection-timeout) you would need to set `spring.data.elasticsearch.client.reactive.endpoints`

Answer (score 2):

In the .properties file, I used the below and solved the issue for me;

```
spring.elasticsearch.rest.uris=http://localhost:<port_number>
spring.data.elasticsearch.client.reactive.endpoints=localhost:<port_number>
```