# Spring Boot and Elasticsearch: NoReachableHostException: Host 'localhost/<unresolved>:9200' not reachable

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

I have a very simple use case, I just want to use Spring Boot (2.5.2) to put documents into an elasticsearch index. I keep seeing this error when the application starts up:

> Caused by: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.NoReachableHostException: Host 'localhost/:9200' not reachable. Cluster state is offline.

It seems to be just loading the default host and port for elasticsearch, but I'm not sure why. I've tried moving the properties around. I've tried not using the Repository, but instead just using the RestHighLevelClient. No matter what, I keep getting this error on startup.

I'm using the spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch

```
implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch'
```

Here's my application.yml

```
spring:
  elasticsearch:
    rest:
      uris: <my host>:<my port>
      username: <username>
      password: <password>
```

The Document object I'm trying to send

```
@Document(indexName = "#{@environment.getProperty('indices.someobject')}", createIndex = false)
public class SomeObjectDocument{
    @Id
    private String id;

    private SomeObject object;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public SomeObject getSomeObject () {
        return someObject;
    }

    public void setSomeObject (SomeObject someObject ) {
        this.someObject = someObject;
    }
}
```

The Client Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.some.company.project.elastic.repository")
public class ElasticClientConfig {
    @Value("${spring.elasticsearch.rest.username}")
    private String elasticUsername;

    @Value("${spring.elasticsearch.rest.password}")
    private String elasticPassword;

    @Value("${spring.elasticsearch.rest.uris}")
    private String uri;

    @Bean
    public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {
        LOG.info(uri);
        ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder()
                .connectedTo(uri)
                .usingSsl()
                .withBasicAuth(elasticUsername, elasticPassword)
                .build();

        return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
    }

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchOperations() {
        return new ElasticsearchRestTemplate(elasticsearchClient());
    }
}
```

And for the Repository, I just created it and didn't add any other methods because I just need to save

```
public interface SomeObjectRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<SomeObjectDocument, String> {

}
```

Comment: what do you have in `<my host>`? if it's `host/` then you need to remove the `/`

Comment: In the spring.elasticsearch.rest.uris property of my application.yml, I have something like ```myhost.company.com:443```, so it doesn't have the ```/```. It looks like the error message I'm actually seeing got cut off a little bit. In the error message, this is the host it's saying is unreachable: "localhost/<unresolved>:9200". I think the <unresolved> is coming from my @Document where I set the indexName, and it's not able to resolve it? I just don't understand why it's using localhost.

Comment: Hi @H.Miller, did you ever fix the issue? I am having the same problem on my end

Comment: look this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69487385/elasticsearch-client-is-defaulting-to-localhost

Comment: @anonuser1234 did you fix this issue? lol

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem about elasticsearch instance. Are you sure elasticsearch instance working on 9200 port ?

Comment: No, elasticsearch is running on a completely different host. I have it configured in the spring.elasticsearch.rest.uris property of my application.yml like "myhost.company.com:443". When I log it in the ElasticClientConfig with "LOG.info(uri);" it does print the "myhost.company.com:443" correctly. I don't know where the localhost:9200 is coming from other than it appears to be the default for elasticsearch.